# What is this called (adjustable angle pipe footplate)?

Tags: pipe, fitting

I'm constructing an EMT pipe tarp canopy frame. It will be a shed roof. One side will be pipe supported (low end) and the other side (high end) will be mounted to the top of my garage roof.

The plan for the garage-side was to use foot plates that have an adjustable angle on them so that they can be mounted flat on top of the roof, then have the pipe fitting adjusted vertically.

It would look like this:

[image]

...except that the connection between the plate and the pipe fitting would be an adjustable angle.

I have seen this before but have no idea what it's called so I can find them online to purchase.

Does anyone know what these are called?

Answer (score 3):

Swivel Pipe Flange: ([amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G96LS14))

[image]

Railing Fittings: ([hollaender.com](http://www.hollaender.com/?page=speedrail), the site has all sorts of stuff like this)

[image]

---

Google search: ([boat canopy chrome swivel joints](https://www.google.com/search?q=boat%20canopy%20arm%20joints&client=firefox-a&hs=Gem&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=IDhZVKT2BtGYyATs6oLgCQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1280&bih=890#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&tbm=isch&q=boat%20canopy%20chrome%20swivel%20%20joints)): ([sheridanmarine.com](http://www.sheridanmarine.com/product/canopy-swivel-mount), accepts 7/8 {sounds like 3/4 EMT to me} ;)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have found a few options under that term. Alas, they seem few and far between. Are these just an uncommon product?

Comment: I'd say they're somewhat a specialty item. Basically for what you're doing, however I came across a warning they're not to be used for 'structure'... Finding the kind to fit EMT may be difficult. -First thing I thought of was the armatures for boat canopies; probably as expensive as those railing fittings.