# Hardware (clamp and/or spacers) to mount a horizontal pipe to a roof?

Tags: roof, pipe, hardware, brackets

Related question: [What is this called (adjustable angle pipe footplate)?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52279/what-is-this-called-adjustable-angle-pipe-footplate/52281#52281)

After posting that previous question, I began to think that there's likely both a cheaper, and sturdier way to accomplish what I'm after.

Here's a sketch of the plan. The gray lines represent the garage. The red and blue lines represent a tarp canopy frame that will be built with 1 3/8" chain link fence pipe and steel brackets.

[image]

The blue line represents the pipe that I'd like to mount to my roof. It would run horizontally. A simple pipe clamp would likely work, but I'd like to get some space between that blue pipe and the roof to allow some air flow (and water, of course, as it needs to reach the gutter).

Is there some sort of sealable roof flange that would give me 6" or so to work with in height that would allow for a pipe clamp to be bolted to the top of it?

EDIT:

If I had to invent something, this is what I was thinking. Essentially a reinforced angle bracket with mounting holes that can be covered by a shingle and a mounting hole in the air that one could bold a pipe clamp to.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that?  Unless you are in the subtropics, this would create a guaranteed mess for snow accumulation, ice, and leaves.

Comment: We maybe get a half inch of snow a year that lasts, at most, for a few hours. No ice. Leaves, yes, but that's a given. Worse case scenario, I'm out a few bent pipes and a ripped tarp. It's a low cost way to get some dry space outside for a while until we can built a proper storage unit on the property.

Comment: Find a local company that installs canvas awnings, they should have what you're looking for.

Comment: @Tester101 I did find those online, but those brackets appear to be proprietary to the awning system and those brackets cost more than what I'm spending on this entire thing. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since this seems to be a temporary canopy, messing around with the roof's integrity (by adding a few attachments) is probably not desirable:  it will cause premature aging of the roof and increase the probability of a leak.  Obviously it can be done, for example solar panels on a roof, but that adds ongoing maintenance to make sure the fastening system is rain proof.

Why not mount the frame under the eaves?  Unless the roof joists are far apart, it probably isn't necessary to run a pipe across.  Instead, fasten each horizontal pipe from the canopy's top to a roof joist (if they are exposed) or to a hefty screw.  If the gutter is in the way, then just use some baling wire between the pipe and the screw.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's 'temporary' in that it will be there until it falls down. :) I shouldn't have an affect on the roof's integrity assuming I can use proper mounting brackets (hence the question). Not too worried about leaks, as these would be properly flashed and sealed and likely mounted on the 'eaves side' anyways. I can't mount to the wall under the eaves as I'd lose too much height to allow for proper slope (plus I lose access to the gutters for easy cleaning)...

Comment: ...Hence the need to try and get some spacers in there above the eave line if at all possible. The top pipe is part of the awning system, so is needed to attach the tarp to.

Answer (score 0):

Galvanized floor flanges for the roof attachment (seal with roof cement)

[image]

EMT connectors, to screw into flanges and tees

[image]

EMT elbows

[image]

and galvanized pipe tees and other fittings as needed

[image]

I have built several low cost awnings like this, it ain't pretty but it **is** cheap. Those other specialty fittings referred to on other replies are designed for specific purposes and either will not fit EMT properly or will be expensive.

Comment: You can raise the horizontal bar off the roof as high as you want using short pieces of EMT; fasten verticle poles to the ground using a "waste nut" flange.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The awning frame will be rectangular with fittings. I then need to take the horizontal bar and somehow clamp it to something that is then attached to the roof. I think these ideas would work if I was attaching perpendicular poles, but not clamping it horizontally.

Comment: I suppose, though...now that I think about it a bit more, I could use the pipe flange, then 6" pipe, then a flange on top, and then screw wood to the flange so that I could then screw a clamp to the wood to hold the bard. A little bit of a work-around but could work...

Comment: Short perpendicular pieces to raise it off the roof, than elbows/tees to attach pieces horizontally across the roof; just like your diagram. Look at two tees next to each other, one oriented 90° to the other and you will see. Or you can try to find side-outlet tees and elbows.

Comment: The catch is finding the right angle fittings to integrate the awning roof fittings into an anchor system fitting. That was the original thought behind avoiding that and just using pipe clamps to clamp the top pipe horizontally.

Comment: You are over complicating this... stop thinking of the roof as a rectangular panel that gets clamped. Use fittings to connect it all together. EMT is easily bent to acquire the proper angle for a sloped roof too.

Comment: Maybe I need a picture. :) But in my head, having too many fittings means you're adding a whole lot of 'wiggle points' that are lessening the rigidity of the overall structure. But I heed your 'overcomplicating things' words. I do tend to do that. I will ponder this some more!